# How can I expand and contract an element so that in its contracted state, it's always positioned above another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element that I contract and expand with a click. In its contracted state, it has to remain above another element. This other element's position will change relative to the viewport. I can't figure out how to do this.

In the examples I show, I want the contracted pink square to always remain above the teal square (the teal square serves ONLY as a marker for where the pink square SHOULD be), and for the expanded pink square to occupy the entire viewport.

There are only three states:

1) The pink element, when contracted, will be above the teal element.

2) As the pink element expands, it moves to the top right corner of the viewport, while simultaneously expanding its width and height to match the viewport's.

3) The pink element occupies the entire viewport.

Right now the contracted pink element doesn't remain on top of the teal element when the viewport is resized.

I have a snippet below and a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ajarana/pen/MmGLME) as well.

```js
let parent = document.getElementById("parent");
let dynamicChild = document.getElementById("dynamicChild");

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (dynamicChild.style.width === '50px') {
    dynamicChild.style.width = '100%';
    dynamicChild.style.height = '100%';

    dynamicChild.style.right = '0';
    dynamicChild.style.top = '0';
  }  else {
    dynamicChild.style.width = '50px';
    dynamicChild.style.height = '50px';

    dynamicChild.style.right = '100px';
    dynamicChild.style.top = '46px';
  }
}, false)
```

```css
/* STATIC, doesn't change */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

/* STATIC, doesn't change */
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

/* STATIC, doesn't change */
#wrapper {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* STATIC, doesn't change */
#parent {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

/* #dynamicChild's width and height change */
#staticChild, #dynamicChild {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

/* STATIC, doesn't change */
#staticChild {
  background-color: teal;
}

/* #dynamicChild's position will change. */
#dynamicChild {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  top: 46px;
  transition-property: width, height, top, right;
  transition-timing-property: ease-in;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-delay: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="staticChild"></div>
    <div id="dynamicChild"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What should happen to the `#parent` and `#wrapper` elements? Should they contain the expanded `#dynamicChild`, or should that element overflow its parents? Are the 'wrapper' elements both necessary, or simply for the purposes of this question?

Comment: `#parent` and `#wrapper` are completely static, they don't change. The wrapper elements are only there to add more detail to my question (but still essential).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but you have your dynamic child to `position: absolute` with `top: 100px`. So it will *always* be rendered 100px below the viewport top.

If you want the static child below the dynamic child:

- raise your dynamic child up
- lower your static child down
- don't use `position: absolute` and `top: 100px`. There are many alternatives

Comment: I just used `position: absolute` and `top: 100px` to better illustrate what I'm trying to do. I'm aware of what it's currently doing. And if I don't use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` then how will I get the expanded state to fill up the entire viewport?

Comment: `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`

Comment: You didn't read my original question. `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh` only solve the final state, which is easy. The contracted pink square has to always on top of the teal square.

Comment: What do you mean by "on top"? Your code snipping shows a contracted pink square "on top" of the teal one, and then expands to 100% x 100%. I don't know how to help you when your example shows - what looks like to me - a correct solution.